# How to get count of successful and failed releases in last 180 days using azure devops rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using rest API to get a list of releases using rest API -

[https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?definitionId={id}&api-version=6.0](https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/%7Borg%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/release/releases?definitionId=%7Bid%7D&api-version=6.0)

This gives me a list of all releases, I want only successful releases in the last 180 days and also failed releases in the last 180 days.

What parameters do I need to pass in this rest API to get information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check deployments instead of releases: [Deployments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) with [DeploymentStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#deploymentstatus)

Try this template:

```
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId={definitionId}&deploymentStatus=succeeded&api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

Comment: This works for getting succeeded deployments , is there any way to pass date parameter in url to get list for required timeline?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below template, but it returns just 100 records. I want full records. How can I get that?

```
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/deployments?$top=1000&definitionId={definitionId}&definitionEnvironmentId={definitionEnvironmentId}&deploymentStatus=succeeded&api-version=6.0
```

**Update 1:**

I found a way for that. You can use **continuationToken** parameter for rest of records. You must assign id of last record to it.

You can think like pagination.

```
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/deployments?$top=1000&definitionId={definitionId}&definitionEnvironmentId={definitionEnvironmentId}&deploymentStatus=succeeded&continuationToken={lastDeploymentId}&api-version=6.0
```